# Is it possible to access the Title of a View from within an ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionfilterattribute

In my views I set the `Title` using the common `ViewBag` approach. I set the value on the `ViewBag` in the view and not in the controller.

The code in the view is run after all four virtual methods in a class that derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`. Thus, when I try to read the title from the `ViewBag` it has not been set yet. Conversely, any value I set inside  one of those methods is at risk of being overwritten later.

I'd prefer not to move these lines into the controllers, mainly because that would require me to edit a large number of views and controllers.

Is there any alternative?

I can't pass the value to the `Attribute` constructor as a parameter because it is not a constant.

Comment: What happens when you have - `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Title = “home page”;` in your action filter? I think you are overriding it some where else in the code. Or is there some error when you assign it in action filter? Also were you able to debug the code?

Comment: I just tried and definitely can access `ViewBag` in my filter. You should check your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It's a timing issue. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you set your Viewbags inside `OnResultExecuting`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi because the values aren't available to me there. The whole point of the drill is to get the values *from* the ViewBag.